# Continous Carousel in Bootstrap 4 (No pause between slides)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been struggling with finding a way to make a carousel stop making pauses between slides e.g. have it roll continously. My example is here on codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/R0iOHHXRYw

```css
.carousel-img-small {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform -2s ease;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 62%">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 text-center" style="background-color: black;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 my-auto" style="background-color: yellow">
      <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1" style="margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <!--
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
-->
        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="carousel-img-small" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/eagle-png-logo/lakes-eagles-png-logo-14.png" alt="Chicago">
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="carousel-img-small" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/eagle-png-logo/lakes-eagles-png-logo-14.png" alt="Chicago">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>

      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The most I managed is slowing down the transition, but can't remove the pause.

I would be grateful for any advice, or a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform -2s ease;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

to

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform -2s ease;
  transition: transform 5s linear left;
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't move at all, could you check out the code I put on codeply?